# Water world short story - maybe called Kraken - using basic chemistry to rebuild society

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading an anthology/collection of sci/fi and fantasy stories sometime between 1990-1996 which had as its first(?) story one called 'Kraken' or 'The Kraken' maybe.

It was about a post apocalyptic water world where the only surviving people were living on floating islands of junk and seaweed.
The most interesting theme to me was that the protagonist rediscovered ways of resynthesising metals and chemicals from the sea and the sun using crude chemistry principles.

Comment: What do you know... I was contemplating asking the same question and I find this :-)

Answer (score 16):

That is "The Blue World" from Jack Vance

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Blue_World

Comment: Thanks - thats it I think.  I must have read the short story version.  Looking forward to read the complete book. :)

Comment: @phantompharter: If you would, click the green checkmark to mark the answer as accepted. It helps our statistics, give you some points, and gives Bigben59 some points.

Comment: It's not actually a post-apocalyptic story.  The Blue World is an alien planet, entirely covered by water, inadvertently colonised by criminals on a prison ship from Earth which crashes there.   They build a society on rafts, each dominated by a clan descended from a particular offending group, and surviving without metal,until they're attacked by a huge sea creature (King Kraken).  It's eventually defeated with harpoons made of iron smelted from blood.  One of Vance's best stand-alone novels, with a similar 'lost world' theme to The Dragon Masters.